# How to upload a file and then insert into it database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't figure out how to upload a file using the upload button and then insert into (along with other stuff) the database.

When I debug into `btnRegister_Click`, HasFile returns false.

Is there a way to persist `HasFile` across 2 different button onclicks?

[image]

Upload code:

```
            <tr>
                <td>Expense Receipt
                </td>
                <td class="blackDisplayName">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplExpenseReceipt" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fuExpenseReceipt" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUploadExpenseReceipt" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnExpenseReceiptUpload_Click" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadExpenseReceipt" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFileWarning" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

C# code behind:

```
protected void btnExpenseReceiptUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!fuExpenseReceipt.HasFile)
    {
        lblFileWarning.Text = "Please browse your computer to load a pdf or jpg file";
        return;
    }

    if (fuExpenseReceipt.PostedFile.ContentLength > 1000000)
    {
        lblFileWarning.Text = "file size must be < 1Mb";
        return;
    }

    //if (!fuExpenseReceipt.PostedFile.ContentType.Equals("application/pdf") | !fuExpenseReceipt.PostedFile.ContentType.Equals("image/jpg"))
    if (!fuExpenseReceipt.PostedFile.ContentType.Equals("application/pdf"))
    {
        lblFileWarning.Text = "Only pdf or jpg files are allowed to be uploaded";
        return;
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Ireland Resources\ExpenseReceipts"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Ireland Resources\ExpenseReceipts");
    }

    string FolderUpload = @"C:\Ireland Resources\ExpenseReceipts\";
    string PostedFile = FolderUpload + User.Identity.Name + "-" + fuExpenseReceipt.PostedFile.FileName;
    fuExpenseReceipt.SaveAs(PostedFile);
}
```

Register code:

```
            <td class="blackDisplayName" align="right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Register" ValidationGroup="ExpenseRegistration"
                    OnClick="btnRegister_Click" CssClass="gray-gradient" SkinID="NONE"/>
            </td>
```

C# code behind:

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!fuExpenseReceipt.HasFile)
        {
            lblFileWarning.Text = "Please browse your computer to load a pdf or jpg file";
            return;
        }

        byte[] expenseReceipt = null;

        Stream fs = fuExpenseReceipt.PostedFile.InputStream;
        byte[] bytFileData = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bytFileData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();
        expenseReceipt = bytFileData;

        int tillID = Int32.Parse(hfTillID.Value);

        double beforeVAT = double.Parse(txtBeforeVAT.Text);
        double VAT = double.Parse(txtVAT.Text);
        double totalAmount = double.Parse(txtExpenseTotal.Text);
        lblExpenseMessage.Visible = true;
        try
        {
            new TillEndOfDayDAL().SaveExpense(StationID, tillID, beforeVAT, VAT, totalAmount, txtExpenseDescription.Text
                , expenseReceipt, Int32.Parse(ddlExpenseTypes.SelectedValue), Page.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper());

            lblExpenseMessage.Text = "Sundry expense has been successfully registered.";

        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to somehow temporarily stash that file server side until it is time to submit. In order to do what you are asking would require the file to be placed into the view state somehow. I bet there is a more efficient way to handle your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by doing the following:

- Removed the `Upload` button
- Moved the `PostBackTrigger` to the end of the 'outer' `UpdatePanel`, which contains **both** the `FileUpload` Control and `Register` button.
- Changed the `PostBackTrigger` `ControlID` to the `Register` button.